# If a is orthogonal to b then $\|a + xb\|\geq \|a\|$

Tags: calculus

Let $d\geq 2$ be a fixed (but arbitrary) integer, and let $a$ and $b$ be a pair of (arbitrary) nonzero vectors in Vd. prove the following statements:

a) if $a$ is orthogonal to $b$, then $\|a + xb\|\geq \|a\|$.

b) if $\|a + xb\|\geq \|a\|$ for every real number $x$, then $a$ is orthogonal to $b$.

Comment: By $Vd$ do you mean $\mathbb R^d$?

Answer (score 2):

to show (a), look at

$$|a+xb|^2 = (a+xb)^T(a+xb) = a^Ta + 2xa^Tb +x^2 b^Tb = |a|^2 + x^2|b|^2 \ge |a|^2.$$

we have $$0 \le |a+xb|^2 -|a|^2 =  2xa^Tb + x^2|b|^2  $$ for all $x.$ evaluating the right hand side at $x = -\frac{a^Tb}{|b|^2},$ we find $-\frac{(a^Tb)^2}{|b|^2}$ this can only be true if $$a^Tb = 0. $$